# Current theme cannot be loadaed due to errors below please select another theme

Tags: kubuntu, themes, plasma

I installed KDE plasma desktop recently  and made some changes . During the changes it seems like I have uninstalled themes as well. Now I am unable to get login interface and it doesn't work at all. So I did try to get in terminal console and  have tried all seq.of ctrl + alt + F1 to F12  to but terminal is not opening as well. I am stuck.

There is error in login interface and it goes like this:
Current theme cannot be loadaed due to errors below please select another theme .
file://use/share/ssdm/themes/Breeze-Noir-Dark/Main.qml :
104:9 : Type WallpaperFader unavailable

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open one, press alt + space, the window to execute the order will appear in the upper part, type konsole and execute it by clicking